# Play audio media in a loop one after the other

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a list of audio links that should play in sequence one after the other. The following code plays only the first audio file and then stops:

```
Future<void> _playPoem(phrases) async {
    List<String> _phrases= [];
    phrases.forEach((phrase) => _phrases.add(phrase.audio));
    _phrases = _phrases.reversed.toList();

    while (_phrases.isNotEmpty) {
      await _playPhrase(_phrases.last);
      _phrases.removeLast();
    }

Future<void> _playPhrase(link) async {
    await _sound.startPlayer(link);
  }
```

What am I missing here?

I am using [`flutter_sound`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_sound)

Comment: Doesn't `startPlayer` complete as soon as playing has started? It doesn't wait for the end of play. For that you need to listen to the end of play event. It doesn't look like `flutter_sound` has that. `audioplayer` has a "completed" event - see https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/audioplayer/latest/audioplayer/AudioPlayerState-class.html